# Is Google play console logs offline crashes when back to online

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I published my mobile app in Google play console recently. Regarding crash logs in Android vitals I'm doing bit investigation on it and I have some doubts,

1. Is Google play console capable of log offline crashes when device back to online ?
2. I could see the crashes updated in Google Play console even I'm working in development apk with my real mobile device, How Google Play console logs the crashes occured it local apk, it is only for the apps downloaded from Google Play store right ?

Please anyone clarify my above questions since I'm new to mobile app development area

.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google will collect crashes even when they occur offline.

Google will collect crashes even if the app is not installed via Play Store. You can however filter those crashes in the Play Console directly by adding the filter "Installed from Google Play":

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks for update on offline crash log. but I could not predict the way how it logs the crashes for the apks that not from play store. I just tested it practically with mobile and tablet. It wont logs the crashes for my tablet.

Comment: I believe it might only log the crashes from APKs that are known to Play, not random builds.

Comment: Here is my scenario: I first installed my app from google play store and uninstalled it after some usage in my ** mobile. But later non play console apks crashes also logging in crashes list. But my tablet it wont work like that when try with the above user scenario. So this mystery is not clear to me. If it only logs the apk known to play then why it logged some of not play apk crashes